# Android Application - Multiple Pages with Static Content

Tags: android

I am looking to create an app that has about 50 pages of static content. I can give an example of what it would look like, so that it will be easy to understand the questions.

1. Imagine a Jokes app, with tens or hundreds of pages
2. The user can see a full list of jokes, which shows the headings in a list view
3. Selecting a joke subject will take them to the joke page
4. From there they can go 'Next' or 'Previous'
5. They should also be able to favorite a joke
6. Going to the Favorites pages, will list the favorites for them
7. The joke pages are static. I could add more jokes with an app update but there is no dynamic content. So I am planning to have any server side code that the app can call.

Now the questions:

1. In Android, can I achieve this with a single activity (for the joke display) and switch the content based on selection?
2. There are several to store the jokes - sqlite, separate html pages or just strings.xml. Which is better for these use cases?
3. If there are multiple headings within a single joke (i.e. formatting as bold for them to stand out), I need to store the formatting along with the content. So HTML looks like the option?
4. This may be out of scope, but I want to capture the content in a standard way so that if I build an iOS app for this, I can just worry about the UI part and use the same content. Again HTML is the option?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can achieve this with a single activity.
2. This is really up to you but Android provides support for SQL Databases. You may also consider looking into content providers.

   *Note*: I would not use strings.xml because you can't load new jokes into strings.xml. If you are getting your jokes dynamically from a website, then you really should either load your content into a database and have the app display from the database, or else just load each html page individually. The html page will be easier as you will basically just be making a browser app, but the database will certainly be faster and cleaner.
3. HTML is certainly an option, though this question seems a little bit vague. It really depends on how you want to get your jokes. If you want to grab them as HTML pages and just display them, then the work is done for you. If you want to parse through them and display them as an android specific app, then it will be more work but you have more control on the app side.
4. Yes if you want your app to work cross platform you can use HTML to standardize your view across multiple devices.

Comment: When I mentioned HTML, I meant create a separate HTML page for each joke, and display them within the activity. What I would like to do is create a header tab for navigation, and switch the content below based on the selection. Any idea which component in Android helps with html content display?

Comment: Well you can use a TabHost: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html and display your webpages in a Webview:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html